# Pairing generic classes in java - how best to execute?

Tags: java, generics

I currently have an abstract class Network and an interface Node. I want to use generics to show what nodes can network accept and what networks can node connect to. My current code is following:

```
public abstract class Network<T extends Node> {
    List<T> nodes;

    public void addNode(T node) {
        nodes.add(node);
        node.setNetwork(this);
    }
}
```

and

```
public interface Node<T extends Network> {
    void setNetwork(T net);
}
```

as well as some other methods, but the problem is already here: calling `setNetwork(this)` is unchecked and can produce an error if someone makes a network of nodes that can't connect to that network class. Is there a better way to do this? Or is that a bad practice in the first place and should be avoided?

Comment: What does `class Network` do? Isn't the network implicitely defined by a set of connected nodes?

Comment: @null basically it is a wrapper around a Set of nodes that allows them to react to changes to the network, get other nodes and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what generics were made for. You'll most likely encounter a wide variety of warnings and errors, if you use this approach. Instead I'd recommend you simply add some sort of Type-ID for each kind of network and checking the network-ID on connection - so when you add a new node to a network.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this correctly. Can you give an example?

Comment: For example (I can't tell what kind of networks you want to simulate with these interfaces), you could use some strings like "TCP" or "HTTP" to uniquely identify all kinds of networks and throw an error, if a node that doesn't support networks with the specified ID wants to connect to a specific network. like this: `if(!node.supports(network.getID())) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Networktype not supported: " + network.getID());`

Comment: I think I'll go with this one. Thanks

Comment: This approach shift problem detection to runtime, which is generally unfavourable. If you're going this way, you may want to introduce marker interfaces to be used as a type parameters. This way, you can have type-safety at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use basic interfaces for the generic `Network` and `Node`:

```
interface Node<N extends Network<?>> {
    void setNetwork(N net);
}

interface Network<N extends Node<?>> {
    public void addNode(N node);
}
```

And then intermediate interfaces for the specific `Network` and `Node`:

```
interface TcpNode extends Node<TcpNetwork> {
}

interface TcpNetwork extends Network<TcpNode> {
}
```

Then this will compile without any type related warnings:

```
class TcpNetworkImpl implements TcpNetwork {

    private List<TcpNode> nodes;

    @Override
    public void addNode(TcpNode node) {
        nodes.add(node);
        node.setNetwork(this);
    }
}

class TcpNetworkNode implements TcpNode{

    private TcpNetwork network;

    @Override
    public void setNetwork(TcpNetwork net) {
        network = net;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can than create further specialized `Network` and `Node` variations independently following the same pattern (adding intermediate interfaces and corresponding implementations)

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem here is that `<T extends Node>` makes use of a raw type, `Node`.

If you change your declaration of `Network` to:

```
public abstract class Network<T extends Node<Network>> {
```

then you ought to be able to call `node.setNetwork(this)` without an unsafe warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do:

```
public interface Network<T extends Node<Network<T>>> {
```